# How is it possible to merge dictionaries with the same keys while renaming the keys?

Tags: python, dictionary, merge, key

I'm working on a project and am in the situation to have multiple dictionaries which all consist of the same length and are also filled with the same keys, every value is a different grayscale picture, so an array.

```
d1 = {'1' : 'a1' , '2' : 'a2' , '3' : 'a3'} 
d2 = {'1' : 'b1' , '2' : 'b2' , '3' : 'b3'} 
d3 = {'1' : 'c1' , '2' : 'c2' , '3' : 'c3'}
```

Do you know how to take these dictionaries and build a big dictionary consisting of all pictures but with keys beginning at 1 and finishing at n, n being the number of pictures ? The order of the pictures doesn't matter.

Like this:

```
d_new = { ' 1 ' : ' a1 ' , ' 2 ' : ' a2 ' , ' 3 ' : ' a3 ' , ' 4 ' : ' b1 ' , ' 5 ' : ' b2 ' , ' 6 ' : ' b3 ' , ' 7 ' : ' c1 ' , ' 8 ' : ' c2 ' , ' 9 ' : ' c3 ' }
```

Because the keys are the same I just get a dictionary with the length of one dictionary when I merge them. It's also not possible to change the names of the keys by hand, then merge the dictionaries, because the number of dictionaries depends on user inputs, ranging from 1 to 104400 dictionaries created.

I also tried nested dictionaries leaving me with the error "not hashable" when trying to access the pictures.

Is there an easy solution to my problem I'm missing ?

Thanks in advance :).

Cheers

EDIT: Thank you guys, most of your solutions were working like a charm :)

Comment: Would it matter if the keys were changed from strings to numbers? Currently you've got '1' '2' etc as strings rather than actual numbers. Also are you on Python 3.6+ and if yes: are the items dictionary entries guaranteed to be in order? If they are you could iterate over each dictionary in order and just procedurally create new numeric keys starting at 1. (I suppose you could then just stick `str()` around it and be back to strings again) How are the input dictionaries supplied? As a list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming all of [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62451466/how-is-it-possible-to-merge-dictionaries-with-the-same-keys-while-renaming-the-k#comment110448471_62451466) is the case, and you can get your input dictionaries as a list. You mentioned you had any number of input dictionaries from 1 to 104400 and that they represent images, so I won't assume anything about your inputs other than it's a list of any-length dicts.

*I will assume you can already put your user inputs into a list already, and we will call this list of dictionaries `d_list`*

i.e.

```
>>>print(d_list)
>>>[{'1' : 'a1' , '2' : 'a2' , '3' : 'a3'}, {'1' : 'b1' , '2' : 'b2' , '3' : 'b3'}, {'1' : 'c1' , '2' : 'c2' , '3' : 'c3'}]
```

So then,

```
i = 1  # we're starting counting at 1
d_new = {}
for orig_dict in d_list:
    for val in orig_dict.values():
        d_new[str(i)] = val  # str() as originals had string keys
        i += 1
```

This should work as Python 3.6+ dictionaries are *ordered*, that is, they remember the order in which items were added to it. So we can more or less treat `dict.values()` as a list.

This should give the exact output you asked for in your question.

Answer (score 6):

By the power of `itertools`!

With string keys:

```
>>> from itertools import chain, count
>>> dicts = [d1, d2, d3]
>>> dict(zip(map(str, count(1)), chain.from_iterable((d.values() for d in dicts))))
{'1': 'a1', '2': 'a2', '3': 'a3', '4': 'b1', '5': 'b2', '6': 'b3', '7': 'c1', '8': 'c2', '9': 'c3'}
```

With int keys:

```
>>> dict(zip(count(1), chain.from_iterable((d.values() for d in dicts))))
{1: 'a1', 2: 'a2', 3: 'a3', 4: 'b1', 5: 'b2', 6: 'b3', 7: 'c1', 8: 'c2', 9: 'c3'}
```

Although the latter is a bit pointless because you could just use a list into which you index zero-based.

Remember that you need Python 3.7 or newer for deterministically ordered dicts.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how:

```
d1 = {'1' : 'a1' , '2' : 'a2' , '3' : 'a3'}

d2 = {'1' : 'b1' , '2' : 'b2' , '3' : 'b3'}

d3 = {'1' : 'c1' , '2' : 'c2' , '3' : 'c3'}

l = [d1, d2, d3]

d_new = {}

i = 1

for d in l:
    for k in d.keys():
        d_new[str(i)] = d[k]
        i += 1

print(d_new)
```

Output:

```
{'1': 'a1', '2': 'a2', '3': 'a3', '4': 'b1', '5': 'b2', '6': 'b3', '7': 'c1', '8': 'c2', '9': 'c3'}
```

---

If the strings need to be padded with a space on both sides:

```
d1 = {'1' : 'a1' , '2' : 'a2' , '3' : 'a3'}

d2 = {'1' : 'b1' , '2' : 'b2' , '3' : 'b3'}

d3 = {'1' : 'c1' , '2' : 'c2' , '3' : 'c3'}

l = [d1, d2, d3]

d_new = {}

i = 1

for d in l:
    for k in d.keys():
        d_new[f" {i} "] = f" {d[k]} "
        i += 1

print(d_new)
```

Output:

```
{' 1 ': ' a1 ', ' 2 ': ' a2 ', ' 3 ': ' a3 ', ' 4 ': ' b1 ', ' 5 ': ' b2 ', ' 6 ': ' b3 ', ' 7 ': ' c1 ', ' 8 ': ' c2 ', ' 9 ': ' c3 '}
```

Comment: yes, thank you, that's exactly what I'm searching for !

Answer (score 1):

```
d1 = {'1' : 'a1' , '2' : 'a2' , '3' : 'a3'}
d2 = {'1' : 'b1' , '2' : 'b2' , '3' : 'b3'}
d3 = {'1' : 'c1' , '2' : 'c2' , '3' : 'c3'}

new_dict = {}
key=1
for old_dict in [d1, d2, d3]:

    for v in old_dict.values():
        new_dict[key] = v
        key += 1
```

Comment: The example output in the question uses strings for the keys. To match this, you could convert to string when assigning elements of the dictionary.  EDIT: I now see that someone has added a comment to the question regarding the above issue, so maybe best wait for response from the OP before changing anything.

Answer (score 1):

Use `itertools.chain()` over the values and `enumerate` as a sequence for the new keys:

```
from itertools import chain


d1 = {'1' : 'a1' , '2' : 'a2' , '3' : 'a3'}
d2 = {'1' : 'b1' , '2' : 'b2' , '3' : 'b3'}
d3 = {'1' : 'c1' , '2' : 'c2' , '3' : 'c3'}


def dict_merge(*dicts):
    return {str(k): v for k, v in enumerate(chain.from_iterable(d.values() for d in dicts), start=1)}


print(dict_merge(d1, d2, d3))
```

Output:

```
{'1': 'a1', '2': 'a2', '3': 'a3', '4': 'b1', '5': 'b2', '6': 'b3', '7': 'c1', '8': 'c2', '9': 'c3'}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from itertools import chain
print({str(k+1):v for (k,v) in enumerate(chain.from_iterable([d.values() for d in [d1,d2,d3] ]))})
```

```
{'1': 'a1', '2': 'a2', '3': 'a3', '4': 'b1', '5': 'b2', '6': 'b3', '7': 'c1', '8': 'c2', '9': 'c3'}
```